# Why this java code works in debug but not in run?

Tags: java, swing, debugging, constructor

Below are the codes. I have excluded import declarations here. IDE.java contains main method. Please look below '//Menus' comment in IDE.java file. That is where the problem starts. I am using java Swing api and when I hit 'debug' the window pops out correctly with menubar containing menu items ("Help" in this case) as I expected. But when I hit 'run' the window pops out but there is no option (menubar is there but it contains no menu item). I am new to this and have no idea where is the problem.

**IDE.java**

```
public class IDE {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    JFrame frame1=new JFrame();
    frame1.setSize(1024,620);
    frame1.setExtendedState(frame1.getExtendedState()|JFrame.MAXIMIZED_BOTH);
    frame1.setVisible(true);
    JMenuBar menubar1=new JMenuBar();
    frame1.setJMenuBar(menubar1);
    //Menus
    JCustomMenu help=new JCustomMenu("Help",1);
    help.init(menubar1);
}}
```

**JCustomMenu.java**

```
public class JCustomMenu extends JMenu{

public JCustomMenu(String s,int x){
    super(s);
    menuid=x;
}

public int menuid=0;

public int init(JMenuBar menubar){
    menubar.add((JMenu)this);
    return 0;
}}
```

What have I missed?

Comment: Did you try moving `frame1.setVisible(true);` to the end of the `main` method?

Comment: Generally you should init your ui before displaying it.

Comment: @Berger & @BackSlash IT WORKED! But how? It seems obvious at first place but when I used simple JMenu instead of JCustomMenu the program worked fine even when I put `frame1.setVisible(true);` above menubar and menu item declaration. What is happening here? (By the way that was the quickest response I have ever got)!

Comment: @Coda : Running in debug mode may change some race conditions, maybe the frame is made visible later than it would be normally, letting the time for the whole GUI to be constructed correctly.Other people here may have more elaborate explanations though.

Comment: @Berger the code when written like I mentioned in my previous comment, worked even in 'Run' mode. I think maybe "_the frame is made visible later than it would be normally_" as you said is responsible here.

Comment: Swing is lazy when it comes to performing updates, think about it, if you adding/remove/moving dozens of components, you only want to perform the update (to the UI) once (you have finished).  Calling `setVisible` last forces the UI to be update, obviously at the end, but if you need to update a UI which is already visible, you need to call `revalidate` and `repaint`